# Automatically Resize Images in .Net WebBrowser Control, Format this in C#

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I found the code [here](http://underwatergoats.blogspot.com/2010/09/automatically-resize-images-in-net.html) which I really need but requires C# format:

Can anyone help me interpret and provide a C# format in my code

Below are my line of codes:

The  first picture/link is the WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted code

[image: The first picture/link is the WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted code]

while the other image link

is the URL Jpeg Images:

How the code gets the url images to display in the web browser

[image: How the code gets the url images to display in the web browser]

How to translate the below code in C#:

Comment: https://converter.telerik.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [converter.telerik.com](http://converter.telerik.com) to translate the c# code you want.

Be careful sometimes you need to correct some aspects.